# Cannot download image in Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, image, qt, download

I am trying to download an image in Qt 4.8 with no success. The behaviour is reproducible with this [link](https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB19puSB9aJ_dhA&w=810&h=419&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQJ5nMpDa99zf3NaJxHx4agrE8wOhZRtGGTOgBjh8SBflzi8MvdsO4p2-S5ghcoVhYQYOB7RR-bPpMWuam3mgbt9CoL_K8NCjeXPmwwVm8HcMgaONaUs6BrHye_qyFrEhMp9p_l3iCC7_b13bpG29BMK&cfs=1&ext=best). If I use another url, then the code works. Also I have tried to write this in Qt 5.7 and it works without any problem. When I open the image, it is not displayed. 
Below is my code:

```
void download()
{
        QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, QNetworkRequest::PreferCache);
    request.setAttribute( QNetworkRequest::CacheSaveControlAttribute, true );
    request.setUrl(url);

    // Create reply
    QNetworkReply * reply = mNetManager->get(request);

    // Connect to signals
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(imageLoaded()));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(dowloadProgressed(qint64,qint64)));
}

void MyClass::imageLoaded() {
    // Get reply
    QNetworkReply * reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

        if (isARedirectedUrl(reply)) {
            setURLToRedirectedUrl(reply);
            return;
        } else {
            QByteArray imageData = reply->readAll();

            // save the image
            QString fileType = reply->url().toString().split(".").last();
            qDebug() << fileType;
            QString diskUrl = QDir::homePath() + "/cache/" + cacheName + "." + fileType;

            QFile imageFile(diskUrl);
            if (imageFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
                imageFile.write(imageData);
            }
        }
    }
    // if there is an error
    else{
        qDebug() << "ERROR loading image";
        mLoading = 1;
        emit loadingChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the image format? Do you have corresponding `imageformats` plugin? Is it loaded correctly? Also notice that you don't check emptiness of `reply->url().toString().split(".")` result.

Comment: The image format should be JPEG. The same behaviour cannot be reproduced with this [link](http://coolwildlife.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-3004/Fox%20Picture%20003.jpg). Shoudn't that be irrelevant though? I mean I am downloading the file and open it (check with different computers)

Comment: Try to debug. Look at all strings you get, look at the file you write. I don't see file extension in your first link.

Comment: I have tried to set up a manual name for the image, the response I receive is "GIF89a..". It is 43 bytes. The actual image should be 75 kb.